# Trying to print data using .innerHTMLlog getting error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fizzbuzz

I am trying to write a simple jquery function that utilizes a javascript "fizzBuzz" function to get a number from the user and print the output.  I am getting an "Uncaught type error"  I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fb").click(function(){
        var num=prompt('please enter a number');
        var convertedNum = +num;
       fizzbuzz(convertedNum);
    });
});

function fizzbuzz(max) {

for (var i=1; i <= max; i++) {
    if (i % 15 == 0)
        document.getElementById("fizz").innerHTMLlog("<li> FizzBuzz</li>");
    else if (i % 3 == 0)
        document.getElementById("fizz").innerHTMLlog("<li> FizzBuzz</li>");
    else if (i % 5 == 0)
        document.getElementById("fizz").innerHTMLlog("<li> FizzBuzz</li>");
    else
        document.getElementById("fizz").innerHTMLlog("<li>" + i + "</li>");
}
```

Comment: wtf innerHTMLlog?... what is it.... Seems that you just wanted `innerHTML`:  `document.getElementById("fizz").innerHTML="<li> FizzBuzz</li>";`

Comment: And why would `innerHTMLlog` be defined, where did you find that function ?

Comment: yeah sry I'm a beginner how should I accomplish this?

Comment: `document.getElementById("fizz").innerHTML="<li> FizzBuzz</li>";`

Comment: @nicael sry that doesn't work.  thx tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fb").click(function(){
        var num=prompt('please enter a number');
        var convertedNum = +num;
       fizzbuzz(convertedNum);
    });
});

function fizzbuzz(max) {

    for (var i=1; i <= max; i++) {
        if (i % 15 == 0)
            $("#fizz").append('<li> FizzBuzz</li>');
        else if (i % 3 == 0)
            $("#fizz").append('<li> Fizz</li>');
        else if (i % 5 == 0)
            $("#fizz").append('<li> Buzz</li>');
        else
            $("#fizz").append("<li>" + i + "</li>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, I love jQuery :)